# VPC IP Not Correct

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I'm trying to get the output of VPC instance IP and the IP not correct here's my configuration

```html
resource "aws_vpc" "default" {
    cidr_block = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
    enable_dns_hostnames = true
    tags {
        Name = "terraform-aws-vpc"
    }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "default" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"
}

/*
  NAT Instance
*/
resource "aws_security_group" "nat" {
    name = "vpc_nat"
    description = "Allow traffic to pass from the private subnet to the internet"

    ingress {
        from_port = 80
        to_port = 80
        protocol = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["${var.private_subnet_cidr}"]
    }
    ingress {
        from_port = 443
        to_port = 443
        protocol = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["${var.private_subnet_cidr}"]
    }
    ingress {
        from_port = 22
        to_port = 22
        protocol = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    ingress {
        from_port = -1
        to_port = -1
        protocol = "icmp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    egress {
        from_port = 80
        to_port = 80
        protocol = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    egress {
        from_port = 443
        to_port = 443
        protocol = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    egress {
        from_port = 22
        to_port = 22
        protocol = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["${var.vpc_cidr}"]
    }
    egress {
        from_port = -1
        to_port = -1
        protocol = "icmp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"

    tags {
        Name = "NAT"
    }
}

resource "aws_instance" "nat" {
    ami = "ami-30913f47" # this is a special ami preconfigured to do NAT
    availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"
    instance_type = "m1.small"
    key_name = "admin_key"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.nat.id}"]
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.eu-west-1a-public.id}"
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    source_dest_check = false

    tags {
        Name = "VPC NAT"
    }
}

resource "aws_eip" "nat" {
    instance = "${aws_instance.nat.id}"
    vpc = true
}

/*
  Public Subnet
*/
resource "aws_subnet" "eu-west-1a-public" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"

    cidr_block = "${var.public_subnet_cidr}"
    availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"

    tags {
        Name = "Public Subnet"
    }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "eu-west-1a-public" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"

    route {
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
        gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.default.id}"
    }

    tags {
        Name = "Public Subnet"
    }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "eu-west-1a-public" {
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.eu-west-1a-public.id}"
    route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.eu-west-1a-public.id}"
}

/*
  Private Subnet
*/
resource "aws_subnet" "eu-west-1a-private" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"

    cidr_block = "${var.private_subnet_cidr}"
    availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"

    tags {
        Name = "Private Subnet"
    }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "eu-west-1a-private" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"

    route {
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
        instance_id = "${aws_instance.nat.id}"
    }

    tags {
        Name = "Private Subnet"
    }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "eu-west-1a-private" {
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.eu-west-1a-private.id}"
    route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.eu-west-1a-private.id}"
}


output "NAT_Private_IP" {
  value = "${aws_instance.nat.private_ip}"
}
```

I have tested the following

```
aws_instance.nat.public_ip
```

and

```
aws_eip.nat.public_ip
```

but no chance about this when using aws_instance.nat.public_ip it's gives not correct ip, this code based on terraform AWS and I'm trying to make VPC bastion host

Comment: It's not overly clear what you're trying to achieve here. Why do you want the NAT instances private IP? And what do you mean by it not giving you the "correct IP"? Surely you only care about the NAT instance's public IP address which is that of the EIP once you attach it (which you haven't done in the above).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying modify the default VPC, see the following:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpc-ip-address-range/

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/3403